# log or ln notation question.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

GM,

is log(e) another way of writing ln ? as
 $$  log_{(e)}  = ln $$

and consequently when 
x=1
$$  log_{(e)}(1+1/2x)  = ln(1+1/2x)  = ln(3/2) =0.405  $$

Please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: So you did not see any thing wrong with above statements ?  
That means log(e) is ln right ?

Comment: $\log_e$ is the same as $\ln$. There's no need for brackets round the $e$.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of the linked question—this question is specifically about equivalence of notation, and the other question is more about the difference between logs to base $10$ and $e$. Its answers focus mainly on differences between the two functions.